# FullCalendar example with database in struts1

Tags: fullcalendar

I am new to struts. Iam developing applcation using struts.Can anyone help in the code for fullcalendar in struts with database ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure just populate your bean with your json to populate the calendar. Then use a define tag on the page and use it to populate your calendar. Here is a simple example.

```
<bean:define id="calendarJson" name="formName" property="bean.calendarJson" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
            <%= calendarJson %>
        );
    });
</script>

<div id="calendar" class="myFullCalendar"></div>
```